# Quartz Trigger Not Firing

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, datasource, quartz-scheduler

I have a java web application which runs on tomcat.
I am using `Quartz 2.3.0`
(Updated to `2.3.2`, still not working)
I am initializing quartz with `Properties` as follows:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", hostname);
properties.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", hostname);
properties.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "5");
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.class", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX");
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered", "true");
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "600000");//until 10 minutes, dont count as a misfire
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval", "100000");
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate");
properties.put("org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "QCP");
properties.put("org.quartz.dataSource.QCP.connectionProvider.class", "mypackage.quartz.QuartzConnectionProvider");
properties.put("org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class", "org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin");//This plugin catches the event of the JVM terminating (such as upon a CRTL-C) and tells the scheuler to shutdown.
properties.put("org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown", "false");
properties.put("org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck", "true");

Scheduler quartzScheduler quartzScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties).getScheduler();     

quartzScheduler.start();
```

then I add a job:

```
JobDetail runnableDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(RunnableJob.class)
                .withIdentity("runnable_JOB", "runnable")
                .storeDurably(true)
                .requestRecovery(false)
                .build();
quartzScheduler.addJob(runnableDetail , true);
```

and then create a trigger for it like this:

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
Trigger trigg = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("runnable_TRIGGER_"+uuid, "runnable")
                .forJob("runnable_JOB", "runnable")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow().withRepeatCount(0))
                .startAt(DateBuilder.futureDate(startDelaySeconds , IntervalUnit.SECOND)) //startDelaySeconds is between 1-300
                .build();

quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(trigg);
```

This is my `RunnableJob` class:

```
public class RunnableJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            //some code
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log the exception
        };
    }
}
```

But the trigger never fires and when I see the `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` table my MySQL database, I can see that the trigger and the job has been added successfully, but when the right time comes to fire the trigger, I see that after some seconds the `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` column changes.

I have already read [this](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/faq.html#questions-about-jobs) and checked these values:

```
quartzScheduler.isStarted();
quartzScheduler.isInStandbyMode();
```

which was: `true` and `false` meaning that the scheduler is in the right state and also my `Trigger` state is `WAITING`.

The stranger thing is that it works fine on my system but it fails when I deploy it on the production system.

I have `Windows 10` on my system and `Centos` and `Tomcat 9` on the server and I'm using `Java 14`.

**UPDATE:**
After some changes(not to the way triggers and jobs are created), now the `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` doesn't update and I checked `catalina.out` and It's filled with this exception:

```
31-Aug-2020 11:04:56.986 INFO [QuartzScheduler_demo123.domain.co-demo123.domain.co_ClusterManager] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1385)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1086)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1197)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1222)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1266)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:697)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)
        at mypackage.quartz.QuartzConnectionProvider.getConnection(QuartzConnectionProvider.java:25)
        at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:780)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3307)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3920)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3957)
- ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'QCP': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'QCP': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread [See nested exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:789)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3307)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3920)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3957)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread
    at mypackage.quartz.QuartzConnectionProvider.getConnection(QuartzConnectionProvider.java:25)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:780)
    ... 4 more
```

The problem did not solve with restarting the tomcat server.

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem seems to be from the data source which I'm trying to get a connection from.
My tomcat instances are defined in `server.xml` file with different `<Host>` tags
and their resources are defined in the `<Context>` tag for each instance of my application:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mysql/hamkelasi" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    
    initialSize="1" maxTotal="50" maxIdle="1" 
    maxWaitMillis="20000" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="600"
    validationQuery="select now();" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"

    username="user" password="pass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="..."
    />
```

And in my `ContextListener` I instantiate a `javax.naming.InitialContext` and then use `.lookup(poolLookupString)`. I tried different approaches here by caching the `InitialContext` or caching data sources but didn't succeed.

Still, the problem is only on the production server with the same configurations and the same libraries.

The error happens when I start the `QuartsScheduler` and when it tries to get a connection from the database. The server and the application are both working fine and only quartz fails with a really weird error saying:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread
```

And also I'm only using the `QuartzScheduler` on one of my applications (for test porpuses)

Comment: And @SoheilRahsaz, when you receive the error, is Tomcat actually running? This happens on application startup? Hoy do you manage your Tomcat instances?

Comment: @jccampanero I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Thank you @SoheilRahsaz. You are right in your update comments: the problem is that when your Quartz scheduler tries to initialize its job store, it is unable to access your database because there is an error when you try to acquire the JNDI resources necessary to lookup the JDBC pool configured for this job store. One thing you can try is, instead of using your own connection provider, try to configure either a direct JNDI URL (```org.quartz.dataSource.NAME.jndiURL```) and let Quartz try to acquire the resources or, to avoid the use of JNDI, configure a direct JDBC connection.

Comment: You can configure a direct JDBC connection with the properties of the form ```org.quartz.dataSource.NAME.driver```, ```org.quartz.dataSource.NAME.URL```, etc. Please, see the docs for a complete reference: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigDataSources.html. Please, can you try?

Comment: Do you need to use mysql ?

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz Any progress on this? Were you able to try any of the solutions suggested in the last comments?

Comment: I know that it's possible to create another connection pool or using a direct connection(which is a really BAD choice because it's too heavy). My application is running on this basis and I want quartz to use the same connections from the given data source. And yes I want to persist my jobs and triggers in database so that I don't lose them after my apps shut down.  So if any of you have any idea why am I getting this weird error, please help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating my MySQL connector version to 8 and using `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` my problem vanished and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

when the quartz job thread picks up the a trigger it will lock the row and updates its nextfire time, else it will go to missfire state.

If you want to dig down in to code and check whats happening
(https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/JobStoreSupport.java#L2831)

Try registering listeners for job and trigger and check if they are getting picked up

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07.html

Comment: As you can see in my question, my trigger should only run once, so it doesn't have a "next fire time"

Comment: Not a relevant answer, prone for a thumbs down!